# Isometric isomorphism between $\mathscr{C}_0(X)/\mathscr{M}$ and $\mathscr{C}_0(F)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, quotient-spaces, isometry

I have some problems with the following exercise:

Let $X$ be a normal locally compact space and $F$ a closed subset of $X$. If $\mathscr{M} \equiv \{f \in \mathscr{C}_0(X) \colon f|_F \equiv 0\}$, then $\mathscr{C}_0(X)/\mathscr{M}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathscr{C}_0(F)$.
(Note that $\mathscr{C}_0(X) \equiv$ all continuous functions $f \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$ we have that $\{|f| \geq \epsilon\} = \{x \in X \colon |f(x)| \geq \epsilon \}$ is compact.)

It is clear that we are to work with the function $\hat{T} \colon \mathscr{C}_0(X)/\mathscr{M} \to \mathscr{C}_0(F)$ defined by $f+\mathscr{M} \mapsto f|_F$. Now it is easy to see that for $f+\mathscr{M} = g+\mathscr{M}$ we have $\hat{T}(f+\mathscr{M})=\hat{T}(g+\mathscr{M})$ and that $\hat{T}(f+\mathscr{M}) = f|_F \in \mathscr{C}_0(F)$, hence our function is well defined. (The second claim follows from the fact that for all $\epsilon$ we have $\{x \in F \colon |f(x)| \geq \epsilon\} = \{|f|\geq \epsilon\} \cap F = (|f|)^{-1}([\epsilon, \infty)) \cap F \subset \{|f|\geq \epsilon\}$; so we have, by continuity of $|f|$ and since $F$ is closed, a closed subset of a compact set, thus it is compact.)
Again it is clear that $\hat{T}$ is injective.
Now my first problem with this exercise comes with showing that $\hat{T}$ is surjective; Since $X$ is normal, one could make use of Tietze's extension Theorem to get a continuous extension of some function $g \in \mathscr{C}_0(F)$ to a continuous function $G$  on all of $X$, satisfying $G|_F = g$ and thus $\hat{T}(G + \mathscr{M}) = g$.

> Question: Yet how can we ensure that $G \in \mathscr{C}_0(X)$?

Question: How can we prove rigorously that $\|\hat{T}(f+\mathscr{M})\| = \|f+ \mathscr{M}\|$, where $\|\hat{T}(f+\mathscr{M})\| = sup_{x \in F} \{|f(x)|\}$ and $\|f+ \mathscr{M}\| = inf \{\|f+g\| \colon g \in \mathscr{M} \}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second question is answered with a straightforward application of [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma), but I'm still stumped with the first

Comment: Don't you mean Question 1? Tietze's Theorem is just a generalization of Urysohn's lemma, but I am not sure if it is that straightforward. How do you ensure that the extension is not only continuous, but that it is also in $\mathscr{C}_0(X)$ ?

Comment: I mean I'm stumped with question 1, I'll write out what I mean for question 2 in an answer.

Comment: Intuitively, I think that it should be possible to ensure that $G$ is in $\mathscr C_0$ by multiplying it by a suitable "bump function", but how exactly the bump function should be constructed eludes me.

Comment: The norm fact is standard for quotient Banach spaces. I have it in my book on Banach spaces (Springer yellow series book).

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, a partial answer.

> **Question 2:** How can we prove rigorously that $\|\hat{T}(f+\mathscr{M})\| = \|f+ \mathscr{M}\|$, where $\|\hat{T}(f+\mathscr{M})\| = sup_{x \in F} \{|f(x)|\}$ and $\|f+ \mathscr{M}\| = inf \{\|f+g\| \colon g \in \mathscr{M} \}$?

We are given an $f \in \mathscr C_0(X)$. Let $U$ be any neighborhood of $F$, i.e. open set with $F \subset U$. By Urysohn's lemma there exists a continuous $S_U:X \to [0,1]$ such that $S_U(x) = 0$ for all $x \in X \setminus U$ and $S_U(x) = 1$ for all $x \in F$. Define
$$
f_U(x) = S_U(x)f(x).
$$
We have $g = f_U - f \in \mathscr M$. Moreover,
We note that $\|f + g\| = \|f_U\| \leq \sup_{x \in U} |f(x)|$.  Thus, we have 
$$
\inf \{\|f+g\| \colon g \in \mathscr{M} \} \leq \inf\{\sup\{|f(x)| : x \in U, U\text{ is a nbhd of }F\}\}.
$$
Because $f$ is in $\mathscr C_0(X)$, we can conclude that this infimum is at most $\sup\{|f(x)| : x \in F\}$, as was desired.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: I guess the idea to question 1 is to not use Tietze, but rather to extend $g$ to 0 outside of $F$. In that case the compactness condition still holds for the extension, however I didn't manage to prove continuity of the extension as of yet. Does a function from $\mathscr{C}_0(F)$ necessarily have to vanish at the boundary of $F$?

Comment: @h3fr43nd it does not.  For instance, if $F$ is compact then we can make no restrictions on what $f \in \mathscr C_0(F)$ does at the boundary

Comment: Do you have a counterexample where such an $f$ wouldn't vanish at the boundary of some compact $F$, yet $f \in \mathscr{C}_0(F)$ is satisfied?

Comment: @h3fr43nd yes.  Any constant function is an element of $\mathscr C_0(F)$

Comment: This is the answer to the problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3504291/485385

Comment: Oh that's a very neat trick.  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: How can you conclude that the infimum in the end can be at most the supremum?

Comment: Because $f \in \mathscr C_0(X)$, $\|f|_F\|$ is finite. So, it suffices to note that for any $\epsilon > 0$,
$$
U_{\epsilon} = \{x : f(x) < \|f|_F\| + \epsilon\}
$$
is an open neighborhood of $F$.