# Exercise 7 page 73 from Conway's book of Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

Following is Exercise 7 page 73 from Conway's book of Functional Analysis :

> Let $X$ be a normal locally compact space and $F$ a closed subset of $X$. If $\mathscr{M} \equiv \{f \in \mathscr{C}_0(X) \colon f|_F \equiv 0\}$, then $\mathscr{C}_0(X)/\mathscr{M}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathscr{C}_0(F)$.
> (Note that $\mathscr{C}_0(X) \equiv$ all continuous functions $f \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$ we have that $\{|f| \geq \epsilon\} = \{x \in X \colon |f(x)| \geq \epsilon \}$ is compact.)

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500252/isometric-isomorphism-between-mathscrc-0x-mathscrm-and-mathscrc-0) there is a partial solution and loses rigor at the end. Also I don't think it is a correct solution at all.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504102/show-that-this-linear-mapping-on-mathscrc-0x-to-mathscrc-0f-is-sur/3504291#3504291) there is another solution which uses one-point compactification which is an overkill and requires not only knowing one-point compactification, but also proving additional results such as "$f : X \to \mathbb C$ is in $\mathscr{C}_0(X)$ iff the function $f^+ : X^+ \to \mathbb C, f^+(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in X$ and $f^+(\infty) = 0$, is continuous". I would like a solution not depending on compactifications.

My attempt isn't much better than the attempts written in the OPs of the two posts I mentioned, anyway, here it is:

1. I think the natural candidate is the function $T \colon \mathscr{C}_0(X)/\mathscr{M} \to \mathscr{C}_0(F)$ defined by $f+\mathscr{M} \mapsto f|_F$.
2. I can easily prove $f+\mathcal{M} = g+\mathcal{M}$ if and only if  $f-g \in \mathcal{M}$ if and if  $(f-g)|_F =0$ if and if
   $T(f+\mathcal{M})=f|_F =g|_F= T(g+\mathcal{M})$. So it seems that $T$ would be well-defined (and injective). But I could not prove that, if $f \in  \mathcal{C}_0(X)$  then $f_F \in \mathcal{C}_0(F)$. So, my proof that $T$ is well-defined is not complete.
3. If could complete the proof that $T$ is well-defined. Then I have no problem showing that it is injective and linear.
4. To prove $T$ is surjective, my idea is to get a function $g \in \mathcal{C}_0(F)$ and build some "bump function" $\psi$, such that $\psi g \in \mathcal{C}_0(X)$ and $T(\psi g)=g$. But, I was able to make this idea work only in the case where $F$ is compact, not just a closed subset of $X$.
5. To prove that $T$ is an isometry, it should be enough to simply apply the definitions of the norms, but it does not work. The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500252/isometric-isomorphism-between-mathscrc-0x-mathscrm-and-mathscrc-0) seems incomplete to me.

Are there any easier rigorous solution for this exercise?

Answer (score 1):

> Let $X$ be a normal locally compact space and $F$ a closed subset of $X$. If $\mathcal{M} \equiv \{f \in \mathcal{C}_0(X) : f|_F = 0\}$, then $\mathcal{C}_0(X)/\mathcal{M}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}_0(F)$.

**Note**: Recall that  $\mathcal{C}_0(X) \equiv$ all continuous functions $f \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ such that for all $\varepsilon >0$ we have that $\{|f| \geq \varepsilon\} = \{x \in X \colon |f(x)| \geq \varepsilon \}$ is compact. The norm of $\mathcal{C}_0(X)$ is the usual sup-norm, that is, for all $f\in \mathcal{C}_0(X)$, $$\|f\| = \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|$$

**Proof**:
Let
$T : \mathcal{C}_0(X)/\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{C}_0(F)$ defined by $f+\mathcal{M} \mapsto f|_F$.

Let us prove that $T$ a isometric isomorphism (and so, we have that $\mathcal{C}_0(X)/\mathcal{M}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}_0(F)$).

**Item a.** $T$ is well-defined. First, note that given any $f \in  \mathcal{C}_0(X)$, we have for all $\varepsilon >0$,
$$\{|f|_F| \geq \varepsilon\}=  \{|f| \geq \varepsilon\} \cap F$$
so, since $F$ is closed, we have that  $\{|f|_F| \geq \varepsilon\}$ is compact. So $f_F \in \mathcal{C}_0(F)$.

Now, note that,  $f+\mathcal{M} = g+\mathcal{M}$ if and only if  $f-g \in \mathcal{M}$ iff $(f-g)|_F =0$ if and if
$$T(f+\mathcal{M})=f|_F =g|_F= T(g+\mathcal{M})$$
So, $T$ is well-defined (In fact, we have also proved that $T$ is injective)

**Item b.** $T$ is linear. It is immediate to see that, for all scalar $\alpha$ and all $f,g \in \mathcal{C}_0(X)$,
\begin{align*}
T(\alpha(f+\mathcal{M})+(g+\mathcal{M})) & =T((\alpha f +g) +\mathcal{M}) = \\ 
&=  (\alpha f +g)|_F = \\ 
&= \alpha f|_F +g|_F = \\
&= \alpha T(f+\mathcal{M}) + T(g+\mathcal{M})
\end{align*}

**Item c.** Let us prove that $T$ is an isometry. Given any $f \in   \mathcal{C}_0(X)$, given any $\delta>0$, let
$$U_\delta =\{x \in X : |f(x)| < \|f|_F\|+ \delta\}$$
Clearly, $U_\delta$ is an open set and $F \subseteq U_\delta$.

By the Urisohn lemma, there is a function $h_\delta: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that, for all $x \in F$,  $h_\delta(x) =1$ and for all $x \in X \setminus U_\delta$,  $h_\delta(x) =0$.

Let $g_\delta = h_\delta f - f$. Then, it is clear that $g_\delta 
|_F=0$, that is $g_\delta \in \mathcal{M}$. Note that
$$ \|f+g_\delta\| =\|h_\delta f\| = \sup_{x \in U_\delta}|f(x)| \leq \|f|_F\|+ \delta $$
So, we have
$$ \|f+ \mathcal{M}\| = \inf\{\|f+g\|: g \in \mathcal{M} \}  \leq \|f|_F\|$$

On the other hand, since $ \|f+ \mathcal{M}\| = \inf\{\|f+g\|: g \in \mathcal{M} \} $, we have that,
given any $\varepsilon >0$, there is $g_\varepsilon \in \mathcal{M}$, such that
$$   \|f+g_\varepsilon\| < \|f+ \mathcal{M}\| + \varepsilon  $$
So
$$\|f|_F\| = \sup_{x \in F} |f(x)| = \sup_{x \in F} |f(x) + g_\varepsilon(x)| \leq \|f+g_\varepsilon\| < \|f+ \mathcal{M}\| + \varepsilon  $$
So
$\|f|_F\| \leq \|f+ \mathcal{M}\|$.

So, we have $\|f|_F\| = \|f+ \mathcal{M}\|$. It means, $\|T(f+\mathcal{M})  \|= \|f+ \mathcal{M}\|$. So $T$ is an isometry.

**Item d.** $T$ is surjective. First, since $T$ is an isometry, it is immediate that the image of $T$ is closed. So, all we need to prove is that the image of $T$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}_0(F)$.

Let $g \in \mathcal{C}_0(F)$ and $\delta >0$.
Using Tietze Theorem, let $h$ be a continuous function defined on $X$ extending $g$.

Then, let  $K=\{|g| \geq \delta/4\}$. We have that $K\subseteq F$ and $K$ is compact.  Moreover $K\subseteq \{x \in X : |h(x)-g(x)| < \varepsilon /4\}$.

Since $X$ is locally compact, there is $K' \subseteq X$ compact such that $K \subseteq \text{int} K'$ and $K'\subseteq \{x \in X : |h(x)-g(x)| < \varepsilon/4\}$.

In fact,  $K\subseteq \{x \in X : h(x) = g(x)\} \subseteq \{x \in X : |h(x)-g(x)| < \varepsilon/4\}$. Since  $X$ is locally compact and $\{x \in X : |h(x)-g(x)| < \varepsilon/4\}$ is open, we have that, for each $x \in K$ there is an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that: $\overline{U_x}$ is compact and  $\overline{U_x} \subseteq \{x \in X : |h(x)-g(x)| < \varepsilon/4\}$. Since $K$ is compact, there is a finite collection $U_{x_1}$ ... $U_{x_k}$, such that $K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^kU_{x_i}$
Take $K'= \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^kU_{x_i}} =\bigcup_{i=1}^k\overline{U_{x_i}}$. Then $K'$ is compact,  $K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^kU_{x_i} \subseteq \text{int} K'$ and $K'\subseteq\{x \in X : |h(x)-g(x)| < \varepsilon/4\}$.

Since $X$ is normal, using Urisohn's lemma, we have that there is $u : X \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous function such that  $u|_K=1$ and $u|_{X\setminus  \text{int} K' } =0$.

Then, let us consider the function $uh$.  It is defined on $X$ and it is continuous (as the product of two continuous function).

Since, for all $\varepsilon_1>0$,  $\{uh \geq \varepsilon_1\}\subseteq \{u > 0\} \subseteq K'$, we have that $\{uh \geq \varepsilon_1\}$ is a closed subset of the compact set $K'$, so $\{uh \geq \varepsilon_1\}$ is compact. So $uh \in \mathcal{C}_0(X)$.

Note that:

1. for all $x\in K$, $u(x)=1$ and $g(x) = h(x)$, so $|g -uh|(x) = |g-h|(x) = 0$.
2. for all $x \in X \setminus K$, $|g(x)| < \varepsilon /4$.
3. for all $x \in  K' \setminus K$, $|h(x) - g(x)| <  \varepsilon /4$ and $|g(x)| < \varepsilon /4$, so $|h(x)| < \varepsilon /2$, so $|g - uh|(x) < \frac{3}{4} \varepsilon$.
4. for all $x \in  X \setminus K'$, since $(X \setminus K') \subseteq (X \setminus \text{int} K')$, we have $u(x)=0$, so  $|g - uh|(x)=|g(x)|$.
5. for all $x \in  X \setminus K'$, since $ (X \setminus K') \subseteq  (X \setminus K)$, using 2, we have  $|g - uh|(x)=|g(x)| < \varepsilon /4 $.

Now, using 1 to 5, we have:
\begin{align*}
\|g- (uh)|_F\| & =\sup\{ |g - uh|(x) : x \in F  \} = \\
&=\sup\{ |g - uh|(x) : x \in (F \cap K' ) \cup(F \setminus K')  \} = \\
&=\max\left \{\sup_{x \in F \cap K'} |g - uh|(x) , \sup_{x \in F \setminus K'}|g - uh|(x)\right\} = \\
&=\max\left \{\sup_{x \in (F \cap K')\setminus K} |g - uh|(x) , \sup_{x \in F \setminus K'}|g - uh|(x)\right\} = \\
&=\max\left\{\sup_{x \in (F \cap K')\setminus K} |g - uh|(x) , \sup_{x \in F \setminus K'}|g|(x)\right\} \leq  \\ 
& \leq \max\left\{ \frac{3}{4}\varepsilon,  \frac{1}{4}\varepsilon  \right\} <\\
&< \varepsilon
\end{align*}
So, the image of $T$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}_0(F)$. So $T$ is surjective.

So, from items a to d, we have that $T$ is an isometic isomorphism. So, $\mathcal{C}_0(X)/\mathcal{M}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}_0(F)$.
$\square$.